# Didn't generate helloworld.obj file when create a new project

Tags: c++

I keep got lnk1184 or lnk1104 problem
it said that cannot open input file "Release/helloworld.obj"

and I get in the directory

`C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\C++Project\helloworld\helloworld\Release"`

It missing the helloworld.obj

and the most terrible problem is that every time I build my project
there will be a cmd.exe and conhost.exe process keep exist
so that if I try to build my project for 10 times, there will have 10 process of cmd.exe and 10 process of conhost.exe.

Comment: every my my project cannot compile anymore but my old project is fine, the problem is that all new project did not generate the obj file, and i have confirm that all my new project configure is same as my old project(C/C++,linker), and just now i have reinstall my vs10, still same situationT^T

Answer (score 0):

Your VS configure may contain errors, ignore this as you are freshman

Create a **New Project** to continue your work...